# Unable to fetch ActiveRecord models based on Rails 7 encrypted field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, activerecord

I have a Rails 7 app and I decided to encrypt a field on an ActiveRecord model. I took the following steps:

1. `bin/rails db:encryption:init`
2. `rails credentials:edit --environment development` and added the keys there
3. Added a `encrypts :name` to the model

Now when I query the model by doing `SomeModel.where(name: 'blah')`, it doesnt return any records even though the record is in the DB.

I can however:

1. Do `SomeModel.all` and verify that the record exists and has the value 'blah' that I'm querying with
2. Make the query work if I change `encrypts: name` to `encrypts: name, deterministic: true`

What am I doing wrong that's making the queries fail on non-deterministically encrypted fields?

Comment: By default, Active Record Encryption uses a `non-deterministic` which `random initialization vector` => means that encrypting the same content with the same password twice will result in different ciphertexts => so querying the database impossible. [reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#deterministic-and-non-deterministic-encryption)

Comment: @LamPhan I get that part that querying the DB is impossible, but I'm trying to do an ActiveRecord query and failing: SomeModel.where(name: 'blah'). Surely that's supposed to work regardless of deterministic or non-deterministic encryption, right?

Comment: @udit - wrong, unless you add deterministic: true

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the encrypted attribute, you need to make the encryption deterministic.

So `encrypts :name, deterministic: true`